# Pandas arrange rows based on duplicate values of selected column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like -

```
ID  NAME    AGE
1   ABC     10
2   XYZ     12
3   PQR     20
4   ABC     25
5   XYZ     30
6   PQR     20
7   KLM     22
8   NOP     16
```

I would like to re-arrange and keep only the following rows based on the duplicate values on `NAME` column -

```
ID  NAME    AGE
1   ABC     10
2   ABC     25
3   XYZ     12
4   XYZ     30
5   PQR     20
6   PQR     20
```

with following rows removed -

```
7   KLM     22
8   NOP     16
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try

```
df[df.duplicated(subset=['NAME'], keep=False)].sort_values(by='NAME')
```

Answer (score 0):

While the most simplest way is the `df.duplicated` solution, here is another take on this using `groupby` and `transform`

```
df[(df.groupby('NAME')['AGE'].transform('size')>1)].sort_values('NAME')
```

Tried performance comparison with `df.duplicated` for curiosity and it about the same for both.

```
df=pd.concat([df]*1000000)

%timeit df1 = df[(df.groupby('NAME')['AGE'].transform('size')>1)].sort_values('NAME')
15.8 s ± 475 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df1 = df[df.duplicated(subset=['NAME'], keep=False)].sort_values(by='NAME')
15.9 s ± 632 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```